# 'indexOf' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: swift, string, swift3, indexof

After migrating Swift 2.0 to 3.0. I had a few mistakes that I have a problem: "'indexOf' is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level" on Swift 3:

// Code

```
var indexIndexed = 0
                    for link in doc.css("li") {
                        if(link.className == "regular-search-result"){
                            for link2 in link.css("span") {
                                if(link2.className == "indexed-biz-name"){
                                    let num:String = link2.text!

                                    let lastPart = num.substring(to: num.index(num.startIndex, offsetBy: num.indexOf(".")!)) // Here

                                    print("le num est \(lastPart)")

                                    let numInt:Int = Int(lastPart)!

                                    if(numInt > 10 && numInt <= 20){
                                        indexIndexed = numInt - 10
                                    } else if(numInt > 20){
                                        indexIndexed = numInt - 20
                                    } else {
                                        indexIndexed = numInt
                                    }
                                    //print(indexIndexed)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: In Swift 3 it is now `index(of: ".")`

Comment: Thank for your reply. @nirav-d
When i use `index(of: ".")` I've this error : Argument labels '(of:)' do not match any available overloads

Comment: You want fraction part from String? For example "12.56"->you want 56, Right?

Comment: Yes for this example but i use indexOf here to : 
`let firstPart = link.innerHTML!.substringFrom(link.innerHTML!.startIndex.advancedBy(link.innerHTML!.index(of:"href=\"")!+6)) `

Comment: Can you add clear Example with what you want in your question.

Comment: Your previous statement was good :
fraction part from String? For example "12.56"->you want 56

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this.

**Option 1**

```
let mynum = "26.53"
if let range = mynum.range(of: ".") {
    let num1 = mynum.substring(to: mynum.index(range.lowerBound, offsetBy: 0)) // 26
    let num = mynum.substring(from: mynum.index(after: range.lowerBound)) // 53 
}
```

**Option 2**

```
let numArr = mynum.characters.split(separator: ".").map(String.init) // ["26","53"]
```

**Option 3**

```
let numArr = mynum.components(separatedBy: ".") // ["26","53"]
```